# Variable has unexpected value

Tags: php

I got this problem. I don't know if I'm just too tired or if there is something not working.

My code is:

```
$sX = ($nr == 1 or $nr == 4 or $nr == 7 ? "0" : ($nr == 2 or $nr == 5 or $nr == 8 ? "200" : "400"));
$sY = ($nr == 1 or $nr == 2 or $nr == 3 ? "0" : ($nr == 4 or $nr == 5 or $nr == 6 ? "200" : "400"));
```

`$nr` is an integer in the range `[1..9]` (it's in a loop). Just right one row below this statement, I output this two vars. And then both of them are `"1"` or `null`. Why? I just can't see it :(

Thanks

Flo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because the ternary operator has a higher operator precedence than logical `or`. Add parentheses around all of your `x or y or z` parts. In other words, you might as well have written that expression as:

```
$sX = ($nr == 1 or $nr == 4 or ($nr == 7 ? "0" : ($nr == 2 or $nr == 5 or ($nr == 8 ? "200" : "400"))));
```

Same for the second one.

Reference: http://php.net/language.operators.precedence

Comment: And better yet, stop using the ternary operator for complex logic, or you'll end up with something completely unreadable.

Answer (score 5):

The direct answer is as SimpleCoder says: you need to fix your operator precedence.

This can be accomplished either by using `||` instead of `or`:

```
$sX = ($nr == 1 || $nr == 4 || $nr == 7 ? "0" :
  ($nr == 2 || $nr == 5 || $nr == 8 ? "200" : "400"));
```

Or parenthesizing (which IMHO is better, because it is foolproof):

```
$sX = (($nr == 1 or $nr == 4 or $nr == 7) ? "0" :
  (($nr == 2 or $nr == 5 or $nr == 8) ? "200" : "400"));
```

Or, maybe even better, rewrite the code to make it simpler:

```
switch($nr % 3) {
    case 1:
        $sX = "0";
        break;
    case 2:
        $sX = "200";
        break;
    default:
        $sX = "400";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `||` instead of `or`. It has a more obvious [precedence](http://php.net/language.operators.precedence), and will do what you want. Otherwise use parenthesis to specify exactly what you expect.

That being said, this statement is quite unreadable, and you should probably break it down into if/else blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to try is:

```
$sX = (($nr == 1 or $nr == 4 or $nr == 7) ? "0" : (($nr == 2 or $nr == 5 or $nr == 8) ? "200" : "400"));
```

Hope that helps.

Also try using `var_dump($sX)` to see exactly what is being calculated.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a shorter example and should solve your problem:

```
$sX = ($nr-1)%3 * 200;
$sY = floor(($nr-1)/3) * 200;
```